# Pin:Insert two different instructions at the same address

Tags: intel-pin

I want to change the function inserted at the timing before the instruction with the same address.

What should I do?

For,example.

```
int count=10;
void insert_check_code(INS ins){
    if(INS_Address(ins) == tmpaddr)
        if(count > 5){
        INS_InsertCall(ins,IPOINT_BEFORE,count--func)
    }else  {
        INS_InsertCall(ins,IPOINT_BEFORE,count_printfunc)
    }


}
```

In the above example,The count value returns to its original I want to change the function inserted at the timing before the instruction with the same address.

What should I do?

For,example.

```
int count=10;
void insert_check_code(INS ins){
    if(INS_Address(ins) == tmpaddr)
        if(count > 5){
        INS_InsertCall(ins,IPOINT_BEFORE,count--func)
    }else  {
        INS_InsertCall(ins,IPOINT_BEFORE,count_printfunc)
    }


}
```

In the above example,The count value returns to its original value.

The target program is a simple server program, so we are using the fork () function.
Is it necessary to write a special description in Pintool for a program using the fork () function?value.

Answer (score 0):

Move the `if-else` code into its own function and insert that function instead:

```
void conditional_func() {
   if(count > 5){
      count_decrement_func()
   } else  {
      count_printfunc()
   }
}

void insert_check_code(INS ins) {
    INS_InsertCall(ins,IPOINT_BEFORE,conditional_func)
}
```

Regarding `fork()`, it depends on what behavior you want when `fork()`ing.

Keep in mind that if the application is multi-threaded, `count` access must be synchronized.